# Returning list results in none

Tags: python, list, return, nonetype

So i am working on a little program to remove duplicates from a given file through a GUI, to learn how to make GUI's with Python.

I have written a method that should take a `string`, turn it into a `list`, remove duplicates from the `list` and it actually does this. 
The problem occurs when i want to `return` the result, because if i `print()` the returned value it just results in `None` being printed. But if i `print()` the value i want to `return` inside the method it prints out the right list.

The class looks like so:

```
#Class that removes the duplicates
class list_cleaner():
    def __init__(self):
        self.result_list = []

    def clean(self,input_string, seperator, target):
        #takes a string and a seperator, and splits the string at the seperator. 
        working_list = self.make_list_from_string(input_string,seperator)

        #identify duplicates, put them in the duplicate_list and remove them from working_list 
        duplicate_list = []
        for entry in working_list:
            instances = 0
            for x in working_list:
                if entry == x:
                    instances =  instances + 1
            if instances > 1:
                #save the found duplicate
                duplicate_list.append(entry)
                #remove the duplicate from working list
                working_list = list(filter((entry).__ne__, working_list))

        self.result_list = working_list + duplicate_list 
        print(self.result_list) #Prints the result list
        return self.result_list
```

The main function looks like so (Note: duplicate_remover is the facade for list_cleaner):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    remover = duplicate_remover()
    x = remover.remove_duplicates("ABC,ABC,ABC,DBA;DBA;DBA,ahahahaha", ",")
    print(x) #Prints none.
```

### TL;DR:

I have a method `f` that returns `list` `l` which is an attribute of a class `C`.

If i `print()` `l` as a part of `f` the values of `l` is being printed.

If i return `l` and store it in a variable outside the scope of `f`, and then `print()` this variable it prints `None`.

Thanks in advance!

## Edit 1:

The `duplicate_remover` code was requested. 
It looks like so:

```
class duplicate_remover():
    def remove_duplicates(self,input_string,seperator):
        my_list_cleaner = list_cleaner()
        my_list_cleaner.clean( input_string = input_string, seperator = seperator)
```

Comment: Looks like `duplicate_remover` is the culprit.

Comment: I will post the duplicate_remover now :) 
(Tried to add it to this comment but formatting)

Comment: Please edit that into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remove_duplicates` forgets to return the return value of `my_list_cleaner.clean(...)`, which leads to the default value `None` being returned.

Comment: I can't believe this is the answer... 
Thanks you very much! 
I will go dig myself a hole now...